# About cylindrical $\sigma$ fields and countably many random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am reading this [article](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=On%20fake%20Brownian%20motions%20Krzysztof%20Oleszkiewicz) and in the second page I am not being able to understand the argument.

In essence we have two random process $(X_t)_{t > 0}$, $(Y_t)_{t > 0}$, such that both have the same finite dimensional distributions.
We are interested in the probability of the event $A:=\{$ path of $(Y_{t_i})_{i \in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly continuous $\}$. It is mentioned that this event depends only on countably many random variables $(Y_{t_i})_{i \in\mathbb{N}}$, and belongs to the cylindrical $\sigma$ field of $(X_t)_{t > 0}$.

If we let $B:=\{$ path of $(X_{t_i})_{i \in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly continuous $\}$, then it apparently follows that $P(A)=P(B)$. Could someone help me understand why is this claim is true and why does it belong to the $\sigma$ field? Is this the consequence of some well known theorem? I have read the pages on Wikipedia about [cylinder sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set) and [cylinder $\sigma$ algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_%CF%83-algebra) but still remain quite confused.

Thanks in advance.